# Python Web Scraper - Trying to get program to scrape data in one specific location not the whole page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've browsed around the web and read and watched several guides online as to how to solve my issue but I'm stuck and am hoping for some input.
I'm trying to build a web scraper that will scrape the M&A deals section from [Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/finance/deals/mergers) and have successfully managed to write a program that can scrape the headline, summary, date, and link for the article. However the issue that I'm trying to resolve is that I want the program to scrape from only the headlines/articles with a summary, which are located directly underneath the Mergers and Acquisitions column. The current program is scraping ALL of the headlines it sees denoted with the tag "article" and attribute/class "story", and thus as a result is not only scraping headlines from the Mergers and Acquisitions column but also the Market News column as well.

I kept getting Attribute Errors once the bot began to start scraping the headlines from the Market News column since the market news columns don't have any summaries and thus no text to pull, causing my code to terminate. I've attempted to fix this with a try/except logic path thinking it would not pull the headlines from the Market News column however the code kept pulling the headlines.

I've tried writing a new line of code that tells the program instead of looking for all tags with articles, look for all tags with , thinking that if I gave the bot a more direct path to follow it would scrape articles going from a top down approach. However, this failed and now my head just hurts. Thank you all in advance!

Here's my code so far below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

website = 'https://www.reuters.com/finance/deals/mergers'
source = requests.get(website).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for article in soup.find_all('article'):
    headline = article.div.a.h3.text.strip()
    #threw in strip() to fix the issue of a bunch of space being printed before the headline title.
    print(headline+ "\n")

    date = article.find("span",class_ = 'timestamp').text
    print(date)

    try: #Put in Try/Except logic to keep the code going
        summary = article.find("div", class_="story-content").p.text
        print(summary + "\n")
        link = article.find('div', class_='story-content').a['href']
        #this bit [href] is the syntax needed for me to pull out the URL from the html code
        origin = "https://www.reuters.com/finance/deals/mergers"
        print(origin + link + "\n")
    except Exception as e:
        summary = None
        link = None

    #This section here is another part I'm working on to get the scraper to go to
    #the next page and continue scraping for headlines, dates, summaries, and links
    next_page = soup.find('a', class_='control-nav-next')["href"]
    source = requests.get(website + next_page).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
```

Comment: short description is usually good for readers. kindly edit your question with sample of the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only change this line:

```py
for article in soup.select('div[class="column1 col col-10"] article'):
```

With this syntax, .select() find all the `article` tags that are beneath `<div class="column1 col col-10">`, which contains the headers you are interested in, and not the others.

Here the documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=select#css-selectors